# Multivariate function for two matrix arguments

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I am busy practicing numpy and one of the questions, I got stuck at. This is the question:
Define function `multivariate_lr` which implements multivariate linear regression. The function takes two arguments: a matrix MxN (M rows, N predictors), and matrix MxK (M rows, K targets). The function should return a matrix of coefficients NxK: so the kth column contains the vector of coefficients for the kth target.

For this task you should not fit the intercept. The OLS estimator for multivariate linear regression with predictor matrix X and target matrix Y is given by the following formula defining the matrix of coefficients B:
    $$
    B = (X^T X)^{-1} X^T Y
    $$
    This is how the function should work:

```
# Example input data
X = numpy.array([[1, -2.9,  1.5], 
                 [1, -0.4,  2.8], 
                 [1, -4.2,  0.9], 
                 [1, -0.7,  2.6], 
                 [1, -1.5,  2.8], 
                 [1,  2.0,  3.6]])
Y = numpy.array([[1.6, -1.6, 1], 
                 [3.2, -3.2, 3],
                 [5.2, -5.2, 5],
                 [2.7, -2.7, 2],
                 [4.3, -4.3, 4],
                 [-2.3, 2.3, -2]])
coef = multivariate_lr(X, Y)
print(coef)

Example output:
[[-11.27451756  11.27451756 -10.79724219]
 [ -2.82477335   2.82477335  -2.63993926]
 [  4.26734863  -4.26734863   4.04619161]]
```

I tried using the model :
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
but it did not work

any help would be great

Comment: `def multivariate_lr(X,Y): return np.linalg.inv(X.T @ X) @ X.T @ Y`

Comment: You can take a look at sklearn ransac regressor too.